# Objective C cuts off last part of string

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

We are working on a plugin for cordova and we want to construct a callback javascript to be ran from native code.

So far the summary, here is the problem:

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"project.notificationCallback('%@',%@);",uuidString , value];
```

This should construct the following example:

```
"project.notificationCallback('uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid',1);"
```

Instead of just returning us the wanted result, it returns:

```
"project.notificationCallback('uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid',1"
```

So it just cuts off the last part of the string, When we do this:

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('jemoeder')"];
```

It all works fine so we think it has something to do with the `%@` and characters not escaping.

Is there somewhere an *obj-c expert* in the house who knows how to escape these characters or is the string just a few characters too long?

Comment: How do you check the resulting string value? your code looks ok and copypasted in xcode produces expected results

Comment: What type are the attributes off, that you want to fill into the string? I just tried it now locally with 2 Strings as attribute (as you have 2x %@) and it works fine, so I assume there could be something wrong with what's going into the string.

Answer (score 0):

If I perform the same stringWithFormat operation, I get:
project.notificationCallback('uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid-uuid',1);

Are you sure NSString *js already contains the unexpected result? Something later on in your code could restrict the length of the string.

As for the maximum length of NSString question, if you posted "nsstring max length" in the search box on the top right of this site, you'd already have an answer (very first result). Also, I'd advise against referring to one's mother in your code samples.

Answer (score 0):

So the error has been found

The result was a datablock received from the bluetooth gatt service. This is always 8 bytes.

So the hexadecimal representation was:

0x31000000

Converted to string this means there are 3 NULL bytes after the value, this stops the NSString formatter from parsing.

Got rid of these little bastards and it´s working again.

Thanks folks.